# Jquery Load Page, return results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, load

I have an installation script that I normally run via a Linux terminal session. I've decided to see if I can make a simple page that has one button and when pressed the script is run.

I've managed to get it to work and pressing the HTML button does run the script and that works fine.

Ideally I'd like to see the output from the script being returned to the page that has the button on it, then I can check the values in the returned data to ensure it's worked correctly. How do I do that ?

This is what I have so far..

This is **index.php**:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#scs").click(function() {
            $("#status").html("<p>Please Wait! TESTING</p>");
        $.ajax({
          url: 'go.php?ab=1',
          complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
            alert(textStatus);
          },
          success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert(textStatus);
          },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
          }
        });
        });
        });
        </script>

<span id="status"><span>
<input type="button" id="scs" value="TEST" />
```

When the SCS Button is pressed the **go.php** page is called and the variable **ab=1** is passed. This runs the following:

**go.php**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['ab']) && $_REQUEST['ab']=='1') {
    exec('sudo /home/user/dowork.script', $out);
    echo $out;
    }
```

This works and the 'dowork.script' is run correctly.
But I want to pass the results from **$out** back to index.php so I can then search for key words.  Eg : YES|INSTALLED|SUCCESS  or NO|FAILED|ERROR

Then if there are no errors I can display one image or if there are errors I can display another.

Comment: but, what is problem? now $out returning to index.php through ajax?

Comment: Yes. How do I pass $out back to index.PNP?

Comment: I've got this working. I'll update my original post with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has worked for me..

```
$("#scs").click(function() {
    $("#status").html("<p>Please Wait! TESTING</p>");
$.ajax({
  url: 'go.php?ab=1',
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
  alert (data);
}
});
});
```

updated go.php to show:

```
if (in_array("OK", $output)) echo "Finished";
```

Now Finished is passed back and displayed in the alert. :)